# Следить за изменениям поле

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-cli

Как мне следить за изменениям поля. Если три раза я изменяю поле после клика на кнопку  Edit, то появляется сообщения в консоле.
Каждый раз считается только после клика на кнопку

```js
data() {
   return {
    wLength: 0
   }
  },
  watch: {
    editWatching(wLength) {
    wLength.length();
      console.log("edited");
   }
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" v-model="wLength"></textarea>
  <button @click="editWatching(wLength)">Edit</button>  
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Vue({
 el: "#app",
 data: {
  text: '',
  fieldDisable: false
 },
 methods: {
  toggleFieldDisable() {
   this.fieldDisable = !this.fieldDisable;
  }
 },
 watch: {
  text: function(value) {
   console.log('Text edited: ', value);
  },
  fieldDisable: function(value) {
   console.log('Button state: ', value);
  }
 }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 <textarea cols="30" rows="10" v-model="text" :disabled="fieldDisable"></textarea>
 <button @click="toggleFieldDisable()">Edit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: нужно vue-cli ...

Comment: @Vitaliy сформулируйте нормально свой вопрос, у вас куча грамматических ошибок которые вперемешку с неопределённостью не дают понять что вы хотите получить на выходе. Причём здесь `vue-cli` ?